# Проверка возможности записи в файл

Tags: c, файлы, файловая-система, fopen

Имеется код:

```
file = fopen (tmpkey, "wb");
if (file == NULL) printf ("ERROR: FileSystem\n");
// Запись дерева
SaveTree(tree, file);
// Закрытие файла
fclose (file);
```

И функция:

```
void SaveTree(struct avlleaf* tree, FILE * file){
  if(tree == NULL) return;

  fwrite(tree->key, 1, sizeof(tree->key), file);
  fwrite(&tree->llupar,  sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);

  SaveTree(tree->right, file);
  SaveTree(tree->left , file);
}
```

Вроде все норм, но когда, например, вместо d.bin пишут /d.bin

По логике должен писать:

> ERROR: FileSystem
>   Т.к. он не может создать файл в корне (нет прав)

А он этого не делает.

Как исправить?

Comment: безотносительно к этому, но `SaveTree` пишет неоднозначно трактуемые данные

Comment: @AndrioSkur с этим позже... Пока мне нужно научиться отлавливать ошибку создания файла

Comment: Так значит он может его там создать, раз ошибки нет.

Comment: Нет - не может :(

Comment: 1) У него тупо прав нету 2) В корне не появилось нового файла

Comment: Можно через проверку существования файла. Под виндой функция _access, под линуксом access, а можно попробовать вот так (через структуру stat) http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-file-exists/

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG, не могу воспроизвести ошибку, у меня всё работает ожидаемым образом, проверьте, что вы пишете в переменную tmpkey.

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, ОС какая? ЗЫ: упоминай через собаку когда отвечаешь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Windows и Linux - код компилится после под 2е ОСи

Comment: Народ, кажется понял - C89 не лучшее решение /

Comment: Перешел на C99 вроде действительно все работает

Comment: Ан нет - та же херня в Windows, ща протестирую в Linux

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, про win (vista+) есть такая штука, как `UAC virtualization` и в таком файл должен отправиться куда-то в `%USER_DIR%/AppData\Local\Virtual Store` — я бы грешил на это... Что под обычным linux испытываешь нечто подобно — я не верю. пока не увижу полноценный [mcve] и вывод (с подробностями запуска)...

Comment: Да, эта херня только в Windows. Спасибо, не знал об этом и искал в C:\